# Parse nested groups

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string with nested groups like this
('blabla' is some text within the string that must be ignored)

```
string Stream1 = @"group ""Main""
                           bla
                           bla
                               group ""Sub1"" -- block-group
                               var1
                               var2
                               endgroup -- block-group ""Sub1""
                               bla
                               bla
                               group ""Sub2"" -- block-group
                               var1
                               endgroup -- block-group ""Sub2""
                               bla
                               group ""Sub3"" -- block-group
                               var1
                               var2
                               var3
                                  group ""SubSub31"" -- block-group
                                  var10
                                  var20
                                  endgroup -- block-group ""SubSub31""
                               endgroup -- block-group ""Sub3""
                           endgroup";
```

The expected output is a list of GroupObjects like this

```
public class GroupObject
    {      
        public string GroupName = ""; // Example: SubSub31
        public string GroupPath = ""; // Example: Main/Sub3/SubSub31
        public List<Var> LocalVar = new List<VarBloc();//Var10,var20
    }
```

I guess some recursive regex will solve this but I can't figure out how to do this.

Can someone give me a hint ?

Sample code would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive regular expression *might* solve the problem - but the complexity of it may be too high to easily maintain (and I speak as someone who once implemented and sold a Regular Expression engine).

I'm *not* going to give you a complete solution - but here's one way to solve the problem.

Your output object needs to change to allow for the nested groups, something like this:

```
public class Group
{      
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GroupPath { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<VarBlock> Variables { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Group> NestedGroups { get; }
}
```

(Note use of properties instead of public members)

Assuming your input stream is a line based format, create a function that divides the string into lines:

```
public Queue<string> GetLines(string definition) { ... }
```

Then, create a routine to parse a group:

```
public Group ParseGroup(Queue<string> lines) { ... }
```

- When this routine encounters the start of a group, it should recursively call itself to parse the nested group and then add the result to `NestedGroups`.
- When this routine encounters the end of a group, it should finish assembling the block, and return the object.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend ANTLR (http://www.antlr.org/) which has been developed for parsing a wide range of semi-structured documents. There's a book (The Definitive ANTLR Reference) which will get you off the ground. It's capable of providing complete parsers for languages such as Java and C#. You can include (Java) code in the parser which will allow you to 
process the results into the data structures you require.